# How to mount a Vivitar series 1 lens to a Nikon D5300?

Tags: lens, nikon, lens-mount, lens-adapter

What lens adapter would I use to attach a Vivitar Series 1 lens to a Nikon D5300?

Comment: What mount is the vivitar lens made with? Vivitar series 1 lenses were sold in a wide variety of lens mounts.

Comment: Also, which vivitar series 1 model?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I use lens brand X on interchangeable lens camera brand Y?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/62000/can-i-use-lens-brand-x-on-interchangeable-lens-camera-brand-y)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I figure out which adapter I need to put an old Vivitar lens on a Minolta body](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/106662)?

Answer (score 3):

Your camera body uses a variant of the [Nikon F mount](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nikon_f_mount), which has the longest [Flange Focal Distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flange_focal_distance) of any commonly used 35mm SLR mount.

You will be able to fully use the lens with your camera **only if it also uses the Nikon F mount**. Otherwise, even if you do find an adapter, the lens would lose infinity focus, which would make it useless for anything other than close-up photography.

Vivitar Series 1 lenses are commonly found for the following mounts:

- **Nikon N/AI** – This is a variant of the F mount that should work with your camera.
- Canon FL/FD
- Konica AR
- M42
- Minolta M/MD
- Olympus OM
- Pentax K